# How to find the number of statements of ontology using Jena

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web

I constructed a big ontology and used the  method listStatements() to display the statements in a model but i wanted to know is there any method in Jena which counts the number of statements generated instead of listing them.

Answer (score 1):

Jena [`Model`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) interface has a method [`size()`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#size--) which should do the trick.

Comment: Thank a lot i have stuck with this problem since last few days

Comment: @user2710605 If this works for you, you should probably [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.  In the future, though, there's no need to be stuck on something like this;  Jena is a pretty well documented, and the [Model interface](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) and explicitly mentions the **size()** method, "size will return the number of statements in a concrete model".